# (C++) Unable to print out the string for output file(notepad)

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, file-io, output

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <fstream>      
#include <iomanip>      
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>     
#include <conio.h>  
using namespace std;

struct Survey           
{        char name[100];        
         int age;           
         char subject;      
         char answer[2][13];    
}taker[10];
struct Health           
{        double weight;     
         double height;     
         double BMI;        
         char BMIcat[100];  
         int marks;         
}health[10];

struct Brain            
{       char brain;         
        int right;          
        int left;           
}brain[10];


  ......


void NameAndAge(Survey taker[], int i)              
{   
    Header();                                                                               //Header.
    cout << "\t\t" << "Please Enter The Information Below." << endl << endl;            

    cout << "Enter your name\t: ";                      
cin.getline(taker[i].name, 100);    


    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    cin.clear();                                                                                        ";                                                          age.
    cin >> taker[i].age;

    system("cls");                                                                                  
}

int main()
{
    char response = 'y';                        
    int oneORboth;
    ofstream outB, outH;
    outB.open("YourResultForBrain.txt");    
    outH.open("YourResultForHealth.txt");                           
    int bil;

    cout << "Enter how many people are going to take the test? ";
    cin >> bil;
    system("cls");

    while(response != 'n')  //Using while loop !n (for repeating survey).
    {
    Header();                                               
    cout << "\t\t\t" << "      Hello And Welcome!" << endl; 
    cout << endl;                                           
    cout << "\t\t\t" << "     Press Enter To Start" ;       
    getch();                                                
    for (int i=0;i<bil;i++)
    {     NameAndAge(taker, i);

   cin>>oneORboth;                                                                      
  system("cls");                                                                            

if(oneORboth == 1)  
{
    Header();                                                                           //Header.
    cout << "\t\t\t" << "There Are Two Categorized Surveys." << endl << endl;           //Information aboutB survey.
    cout << "\t\t" << "   Categories: 1. Health    2. Left-Right Brain" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter a category: ";                                                     
    cin >> taker[i].subject;
    switch(taker[i].subject)
    {
        case '1':                           
            WeightAndHeight(health,i);      
            HQ(taker, health,i);                
            break;                          

        case '2':                           
            BQ(taker, brain,i);                 
            break;                          
    }
}

if(oneORboth == 2)  //If taker wants to do both surveys.
{   
        HeaderHealth();                                     
        cout << "\t\t\t" << "     First Survey; Health";    
        cout << endl << endl;                               
        cout << "\t\t\t" << "     Press Enter To Start" ;   
        getch();                                            
        WeightAndHeight(health,i);                      
        HQ(taker, health,i);                                
        HeaderBrain();                                      
        cout << "\t\t\t" << "     Second Survey; Brain";    
        cout << endl << endl;                               
        cout << "\t\t\t" << "     Press Enter To Start" ;   
        getch();                                            
        BQ(taker, brain,i);;                                     

}

float m;                            
m = health[i].height / 100;
health[i].BMI = health[i].weight/(m*m); 


if(health[i].BMI < 18.5)
    strcpy(health[i].BMIcat,"Underweight");
if((health[i].BMI >= 18.50) && (health[i].BMI<= 24.99))
    strcpy(health[i].BMIcat, "Normal");
if((health[i].BMI >= 25.00) && (health[i].BMI <= 29.99))
    strcpy(health[i].BMIcat, "Overweight");
if(health[i].BMI >= 30.00)
    strcpy(health[i].BMIcat, "Obese");



if(taker[i].subject == '1')                             
{
    outH<< "Name\t\t: " << taker[i].name << endl;           
    outH << "Age\t\t: " << taker[i].age<< endl;         
    outH << setiosflags (ios::fixed);
    outH << setiosflags (ios::showpoint);               
    outH << setprecision(2);
    outH << "Weight\t\t: " << health[i].weight << endl; 
    outH << "Height\t\t: " << health[i].height << endl; 
    outH << "BMI\t\t: " << health[i].BMI << endl;           
    outH << "BMI Category: " << health[i].BMIcat << endl;
    outH << "Correct Answer: "<<health[i].marks << endl;    

}
if(taker[i].subject == '2')             
{       
    outB << "Name: " <<  taker[i].name << endl; 
    outB << "Age : " << taker[i].age << endl;   

    if(brain[i].right > brain[i].left)              
    {
        outB << endl;
        outB << "You are Right-Brained!" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "The Right Brain:" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "Unique Traits: " << endl;
        outB << "Recognizes faces easily" << endl;
        outB << "Expressive" << endl;
        outB << "Musical" << endl;
        outB << "Reads emotions easily" << endl;
        outB << "Colorful" << endl;
        outB << "Imaginative" << endl;
        outB << "Intuitiove" << endl;
        outB << "Creative" << endl;

    }
    if(brain[i].left > brain[i].right)          
    {
        outB << endl;
        outB << "You are Left-Brained!" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                        
        outB << "The Left Brain " << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "Unique Traits: " << endl;
        outB << "Language learner" << endl;
        outB << "Logical" << endl;
        outB << "Critical thinker" << endl;
        outB << "Great with numbers" << endl;
                        //Closes brain output.
    }                                   
}

if(oneORboth == 2)  /* TATA */
{
    outH << "Name\t\t: " << taker[i].name << endl;      
    outH << "Age\t\t: " << taker[i].age << endl;            
    outH << setiosflags (ios::fixed);
    outH << setiosflags (ios::showpoint);               
    outH << setprecision(2);
    outH << "Weight\t\t: " << health[i].weight<< endl;  
    outH << "Height\t\t: " << health[i].height<< endl;  
    outH << "BMI\t\t: " << health[i].BMI<< endl;            
    outH << "BMI Category: " << health[i].BMIcat  << endl;
    outH<< "Correct Answer: "<<health[i].marks << endl; 

}
if(oneORboth == 2)  
{
    outB << "Name: " <<  taker[i].name << endl;         
    outB << "Age : " << taker[i].age << endl;           

    if(brain[i].right > brain[i].left)      
    {
        outB << endl;
        outB << "You are Right-Brained!" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "The Right Brain:" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "Unique Traits: " << endl;
        outB << "Recognizes faces easily" << endl;
        outB << "Expressive" << endl;
        outB << "Musical" << endl;
        outB << "Reads emotions easily" << endl;
        outB << "Colorful" << endl;
        outB << "Imaginative" << endl;
        outB << "Intuitiove" << endl;
        outB << "Creative" << endl;

    }
    if(brain[i].left > brain[i].right)      
    {
        outB << endl;
        outB << "You are Left-Brained!" << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                        
        outB << "The Left Brain " << endl;
        outB << barline << endl;                            
        outB << "Unique Traits: " << endl;
        outB << "Language learner" << endl;
        outB << "Logical" << endl;
        outB << "Critical thinker" << endl;
        outB << "Great with numbers" << endl;

    }
}

}
cout << barline << headline << barline;
cout << endl << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t\t     Retake?" << endl << endl;
cout << barline << barline << barline << endl << endl;

cout << "y for Yes, n for No." << endl; 
cout << "Take survey again?" << endl;   
cin >> response;                        
system("cls");                          

if(response == 'n')                     
Credit();       
outH.close();                   
outB.close();       

return 0;   

 }
}
```

Been trying to fix the code for hours now and no progression is made.
Everything works out perfectly except for the part where it prints out the name of the taker into notepad (think it as a receipt).
I'm suspecting that this part has some problem but i couldn't detect what is it.

```
void NameAndAge(Survey taker[], int i)              
    {   
        Header();                                                                       
        cout << "\t\t" << "Please Enter The Information Below." << endl << endl;            

        cout << "Enter your name\t: ";                                  


    cin.getline(taker[i].name, 100);    
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
     cin.clear();   
    cout << "\nEnter your age\t: ";                             
    cin >> taker[i].age;
        system("cls");                                                                                  
    }
```

I only post only some parts of the code because the original one is too long.

Comment: You *suspect* there is a problem? Does the code work? If not, exactly how does it not work? What have you tried so far (debugger, print statements...) to solve it yourself?

Comment: The code works. But it doesn't print out the name of the takers in the output file(notepad). The other information such as age, BMI, etc appeared.

Comment: @FeiXiang Hey, Thanks for dropping by and comment. I already fixed the problem and the code works fine.